# SharePoint Online : Submit data to multiple lists using infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a SharePoint Online List customized in Infopath. This list has Parent-Child relationship with other list. On form submit, I need to submit data to this list(parent) as well as Child list too. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but hopefully this will help someone out. It can be done with OOTB functionality, using a SharePoint Designer workflow.

This is how I do it:
"main list" = The main data connection in the InfoPath form
"secondary list" = The other list you would like to submit to

1. Open SPD, and navigate to the main list
2. In the Workflow section, click "New"
3. Create your workflow
4. Add the Action: "Update item in this list"
5. Click "this list"
6. Select the secondary list you are submitting to, from the drop down
7. Click "Add..."
8. Select the field in the secondary list you need to submit to
9. Select the field in the main list whose value will be used to update the field you selected in step 6

Now you need to identify the specific item in the secondary list you want to update. In this example I am matching the ID in the secondary list, with the ID of the current item

8. In the "Field" drop down, select "ID"
9. In the "Value" drop down, select "Current item", then "ID"

I hope I explained steps 8 and 9 well enough. The fields to match are dependent on your specific needs. I chose "ID" because we can all relate to that.